# Visual Studio Workflows and Sharepoint

Tags: 2007, workflow, visual-studio

I am new to designing workflows in Visual Studio (2010) for MOSS 2007. I have a "best practices" question:

I have two separate, unrelated processes on one content type I need to manage with WFs. The first is sending and collecting approvals from users. The second is sending emails to users at 30, 60, 83, and 90 day intervals notifying them of a pending expiration of thier list item.

My question is should these be handled in the same workflow by adding a parallel sequence with delay activities or should I create two workflows and attach both to the content type? It seems to me that a workflow is focused on one set of related tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar scenario, and even though it would make sense to throw it all in one workflow, I would (and did) separate it out into two workflows, one for Approvals, and one for Notifications. You can handle the Notifications with Pausing the workflow, and not tie up the Approval process.

Comment: After playing around with it I had the same thought about tying up the workflow. Adding the parallel task also made the WF much more complicated. I just wasn't sure if throwing two workflows on the same content type was recommended. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, if something goes wrong or you miss something, you don't need to redeploy a massive workflow again, you can just open the workflow with the flaw. Cheers!